# Razor parent component detect if child component exists

Tags: asp.net, razor, blazor

I am using the default Blazor server application for building a login page. I am creating my own UI "framework" of components and i wanted to see if its possible to have the Parent component detect if there is a certain child component. If the child component was provided then change the Parent component html structure.

Login page that consumes the components:

```
<Card Color="bg-info">
    <CardHeader>Card Header</CardHeader>
    <CardBody>
        <CardTitle>Card title</CardTitle>
        <CardTitle SubTitle>Card Subtitle</CardTitle>
        <CardText>Card text goes here...</CardText>
    </CardBody>
    <CardFooter>
        <Spacer />
        <Button Color="bg-danger">Cancel</Button>
        <Button class="ms-2" Color="bg-primary" @onclick="Test">Ok</Button>
    </CardFooter>
</Card>
```

Card(parent) component:

```
<div @attributes="AdditionalAttributes" class="@BaseCss" style="@BaseStyles">
    @ChildContent
</div>
```

So what i'm looking for is, IF the consumer of the `<Card>` component has opted to use the `<CardHeader>` child component inside of `<Card>` then problematically change the html template of the Card component

Something like this, but im not sure how to implement it:

```
<div @attributes="AdditionalAttributes" class="@BaseCss" style="@BaseStyles">
    @if (HEADER_COMPONENT_EXISTS) <----- How do i get this?
    {
        @HEADER_COMPONENT_HERE <------ How can i add this RenderFragment
        <div class="card-body">
            @ChildContent
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="card-body">
            @ChildContent
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are the `CardHeader`, `CardBody` and `CardFooter` components used anywhere else? If not, you could simply use these as parameters directly in your `Card` component as follows:

```
<div @attributes="AdditionalAttributes" class="@BaseCss" style="@BaseStyles">
    @CardHeader
    <div class="card-body">
        @CardBody
    </div>
    @CardFooter
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment CardHeader { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment CardBody { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment CardFooter { get; set; }
}
```

If no `<CardHeader> </CardHeader>` has been added inside `<Card> </Card>`, nothing is rendered for `@CardHeader`.

---

You can verify either `Parameter` existence by checking it against `null`:

```
<div @attributes="AdditionalAttributes" class="@BaseCss" style="@BaseStyles">
    @if (CardHeader != null)
    {
        @CardHeader
        <!-- Other header-relevant content -->
    }
    @CardBody
</div>
```

---

Note: If you want to keep `ChildContent` as a parameter for `Card` as well, that child content needs to be wrapped inside `<ChildContent> </ChildContent>`:

```
<Card Color="bg-info">
    <CardHeader><!--Header content--></CardHeader>
    <CardBody><!--Body content--></CardBody>
    <CardFooter><!--Footer content--></CardFooter>
    <ChildContent><!--Other content--></ChildContent>
    <!--Any content that goes here will get an error message-->
</Card>
```

This is the case for *any* component if it takes more than one parameter of the `RenderFragment` type.

Comment: This didn't work because now its complaining "Unrecognized child content inside component 'Card'. The component 'Card' accepts child content through the following top-level items: 'CardHeader', 'CardBody', 'CardFooter', 'ChildContent'"

Comment: Do you have anything else inside your `<Card> </Card>` that is _not_ wrapped inside `<CardHeader> </CardHeader>`, `<CardBody> </CardBody>` or `<CardFooter>`? If so, it needs to be wrapped inside `<ChildContent> </ChildContent>` -- it cannot stand alone inside `<Card> </Card>`, seeing as there's now more than one `RenderFragment` paramter.

Comment: Answer updated with an example.

Comment: That works, but defeats the purpose of the original idea of the question. Was hoping there was a way to not have to wrap the 'body' of the card and just detect the <Header/> and <Footer />

Comment: I understand. I honestly don't think that is possible, at least not using Blazor alone. I suppose you could try attributing the outermost element in your `CardHeader` razor file with a specific `name`, and then in an overridden `OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)` in your `Card` logic you could search for an element in the DOM inside the rendered `Card` element having that `[name]` to find out if it exists. (I have never tried that approach, though, and even if it works, I wouldn't really recommend it over using the `RenderFragment`-wrapping approach.)