# How do I control the structure of Razor components?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, blazor

I'm using razor components to build a design system.

My goals are to:

1. Have parent components (eg. `Card`) that can have several child components (eg. `CardDescription`, `CardTitle` and `CardBody`)
2. Use the parent `Card` component control the position where the children components are rendered
3. Allow access to the attributes of the child components (ie. `CardDescription.AlignParam`, `CardTitle.SizeParam` and `CardBody.BodyParam`) outside of the parent component

How could I achieve this?

Here's how I would like to consume the parent `Card` component in a Blazor server page (eg. Index.razor)

```
<Card>
    <CardDescription AlignParam="None">
        <CardTitle SizeParam="big" OtherParam="happy">
            Amazing title
        </CardTitle>
    </CardDescription>
    <CardBody BodyParam="rounded-card blue-card">
        other longer content
    </CardBody>
</Card>
```

This my current (incorrect) implementation for `Card.razor`

```
<div class="container-card">
    @if (CardBody == null)
    {
        @* Code always go here *@
        @ChildContent
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="something-desc">
            @CardDescription
        </div>
        <div class="something-body">
            @CardBody
        </div>
        @if (ChildContent != null)
        {
            <div class="some-other-child">
                @ChildContent
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public CardDescription? CardDescription { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public CardBody? CardBody { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public CardTitle? CardTitle { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

This is my implementation for `CardTitle.razor`

```
<div class="container-card-title">
    @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? SizeParam { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? OtherParam { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    // Other details
}
```

This is the implementation for `CardDescription.razor`

```
<div class="container-card-desc">
    @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? AlignParam { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    // Other details
}
```

This is `CardBody.razor`

```
<div class="container-card-title">
    @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? BodyParam { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? OtherParam { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    // Other details
}
```

My environment is Asp.Net Core 7.0.5

Comment: Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70896317/razor-parent-component-detect-if-child-component-exists).

Answer (score 1):

You can probably collapse all those components into a single component with `RenderFragments`  Here's a quick demo to show how you can do that.

```cs
<div class="container-card">
        <div class="@this.DescriptionCss">
            @this.DescriptionContent
        </div>
        <div class="something-body">
            @this.BodyContent
        </div>
        @if (ChildContent != null)
        {
            <div class="some-other-child">
                @ChildContent
            </div>
        }
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter] public string? DescriptionCss { get; set; } = "big"; 
    [Parameter] public string? TitleCss { get; set; } = "big";
    [Parameter] public string? BodyCss { get; set; } = "big";

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? DescriptionContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? BodyContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

And `Index`

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<MyCard DescriptionCss="m-2 p-4">
    <DescriptionContent>
        <h1>
            A BIG HELLO
        </h1>
    </DescriptionContent>
    <BodyContent>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            Hello Blazor
        </div>
        </BodyContent>
</MyCard>
```

When you say:

*Allow access to the attributes of the child components (ie. CardDescription.AlignParam, CardTitle.SizeParam and CardBody.BodyParam) outside of the parent component*

Does this above satisfy your need, or if not who is the consumer?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I don't want to have to put the child attributes on the parent. This quickly becomes unwieldily for more complex use-cases.

Comment: If there were only one RenderFragment ChildContent, is there a way to intercept each ChildContent when a child component is added?

Or is there a way to infer then instantiate each of the parameters (ie. CardDescription, CardBody, CardTitle) from the ChildContent?

Comment: It was only a suggestion based on the information you gave. There's a very modern technique which I've dubbed component registration that can be used. The new QuickGrid uses it. Take a look a the source code.  Why do you want external access to all these?

Comment: Thanks MrC. I'll have a look at it.